# excelDNA memory management of c API

Tags: memory-management

I am trying to call xlfCaller from excelDna by method XlCall.TryExcel, I got XlReturnStackOvfl sometimes, i found something for this problem:1. at this site:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/xlfcaller, it says we must call  xlFree after xlfCaller, 2. at https://docs.excel-dna.net/excel-c-api/, it shows that "Excel-DNA takes care of all type conversion and memory management for the C API calls.", so I am wondering, do I need to call xlFree?

Answer (score 0):

excelDna always call xlFree after calling excel c APIs, so we dont need to call xlFree again.Below is source code of excelDna:

```
private unsafe static int TryExcelImpl4(int xlFunction, out object result, params object[] parameters)
    {
        int xlReturn;

        // Set up the memory to hold the result from the call
        XlOper resultOper = new XlOper();
        resultOper.xlType = XlType.XlTypeEmpty;
        XlOper* pResultOper = &resultOper;  // No need to pin for local struct

        // Special kind of ObjectArrayMarshaler for the parameters (rank 1)
        using (XlObjectArrayMarshaler paramMarshaler = new XlObjectArrayMarshaler(1, true))
        {
            XlOper** ppOperParameters = (XlOper**)paramMarshaler.MarshalManagedToNative(parameters);
            xlReturn = Excel4v(xlFunction, pResultOper, parameters.Length, ppOperParameters);
        }

        // pResultOper now holds the result of the evaluated function
        // Get ObjectMarshaler for the return value
        ICustomMarshaler m = XlObjectMarshaler.GetInstance("");
        result = m.MarshalNativeToManaged((IntPtr)pResultOper);
        // And free any memory allocated by Excel
        Excel4v(xlFree, (XlOper*)IntPtr.Zero, 1, &pResultOper);
    
        return xlReturn;
    }
```